# What escrow system does the official Bitcoin bounty progam use?

Tags: escrow

There is a list of bounties on the wiki here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Active_Bounties

How are the BTC pledges collated and eventually paid? I assume there is some kind of escrow system but I can't find out anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

Multisignature transactions can act as escrow.

A transaction could require a party and a trusted third party to complete, or it could be the trusted third party alone who signs to complete the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Usually they're a multisig transaction between a couple of core developers. One recent one was a 2-of-3 between Greg Maxwell and a couple of others. It's mainly just to prevent hit-by-a-bus scenarios, we trust in these people absolutely.